# Symbols leak into Global context when using Information

Tags: bugs, front-end, contexts, internals, usage-messages

**Bug introduced before 12.1.0, fixed in 13.3.0 [CASE:4972508]**

---

When debugging I found the following peculiar behaviour of `Information`:

```
$Version
Do[
    Remove["Global`*"]//Quiet;
    Information@ToExpression@str;
    Names["Global`*"]//Sow,
    {str,Alphabet[]}
]//Reap//Last//First//Column
Remove["Global`*"]//Quiet;
```

[image]

Other context is ok:
[image]

Here is the result from my friend.
[image]

**Where are these unexpected symbols coming from?**

Comment: What is your question? Why do you find this peculiar?

Comment: @lericr I'm also unsure about the question, but the creation of seemingly random symbols in the global context is indeed unexpected...

Comment: Well, they're clearly not random. My assumption is that there is work going on that inspects what you "type" for the purpose of anticipating computational needs. Totally a guess. Don't get me wrong, I wouldn't have guessed that this happens, but seeing it happen doesn't cause much surprise for me.

Comment: But I'm also pointing out that you didn't ask a question. You sort of made a judgment ("peculiar"), but that's an opinion that's not really relevant. Is your question simply "why do symbols get added to Global context?" If so, just ask. Also, a simpler example would suffice to motivate the question. But maybe you have a more specific/nuanced question.

Comment: Oh, I see you updated the post with a question.

Comment: You can use `$NewSymbol` to investigate this problem, this make it possible to see what symbols (whetherever they are in `Global` ) are created around the time of creation of ```Global` ``` symbols.

Comment: I tried that for `Information@e`. It creates 220 symbols. Most of them are removed, and only 1 symbol `HashTable` is in `Global`.

Comment: Your code is incredibly hard to read with all of those unnecessary `Reap`, `Sow`, and `Remove` statements, not to mention the excessive postfix notation.  A much simpler code to demonstrate the problem is here: https://pastebin.com/raw/PDq3Bkdi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to usage message, with which `Information` attempts to provide for user.

```
tmp`list1 = Reap[Do[
    Remove["Global`*"]//Quiet;
    Information@ToExpression@str;
    Names["Global`*"]//Sow,
    {str, Alphabet[]}
]][[2,1]];
Remove["Global`*"]//Quiet;
tmp`list2 = Reap[Do[
    Remove["Global`*"]//Quiet;
    MessageName[Evaluate@ToExpression@str, "usage"];
    Names["Global`*"]//Sow,
    {str, Alphabet[]}
]][[2,1]];
tmp`list1 === tmp`list2
(* True *)
```

These symbols seems all to be obsolete symbols with usage messages, even for those in `Global`:

```
In[1]:= Global`HashTable::usage

Out[1]= "HashTable is a part of the object which is returned by Dispatch."
```

This is from `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Kernel/TextResources/ChineseSimplified/Usage.m` , `English` and `Japanese` seem to not have this problem.

I've already reported this to WRI.

Comment: Thx! `$NewSymbol` is very useful.