# How to construct the HoldAll version of Information[]?

Tags: hold, attributes

When building other functions I need the `HoldAll` version of `Information`, and the usual method seems not to work.

Firstly as a comparison, the `HoldAll` version of `Head` can be constructed as

```
SetAttributes[{g0,g1},{HoldAll}];
g0[sym_Symbol]:=Head[Unevaluated@sym];

g1[sym_Symbol]:=
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{Head},
        Unprotect@Head;
        SetAttributes[Head,{HoldAll}];
        Head@sym
    ];

test:=(++a;Print@a;a);
```

and they give the expected results:

```
a=1;
g0@test
g1@test

(*Symbol*)
(*Symbol*)
```

However for `Information`,

```
SetAttributes[{f0,f1},{HoldAll}];

f0[sym_Symbol]:=Information[Unevaluated@sym];

f1[sym_Symbol]:=
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{Information},
        Unprotect@Information;
        SetAttributes[Information,{HoldAll}];
        Information@sym
    ];
```

the `test` function will be evaluated inside the `HoldAll` version of `Information` - `f0` and `f1`, in contrast to the operator `??`:
[image]

It seems that there are some internal functions inside `Information` blocking the `HoldAll` attributes. Besides this, `Information` alse has [other side effect](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271914/).

How to understand this, and build a correct `HoldAll` version of `Information`?

Comment: `??test` calls `Information["test"]`. Would throwing in a `SymbolName` as in `f0[sym_Symbol] := Information[SymbolName@Unevaluated@sym]` do what you want?

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I want. It seems that `Information[_Symbol]` is built from `Information[_String]`, and all these side effects come from convert expressions into strings? @user293787

Comment: @user293787 btw you can add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: There are much more knowledgeable people here, perhaps you may want to leave the question open to get more feedback. I have no idea what `Information` does when given a symbol!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html), the special form `??test` calls `Information["test"]`.

Therefore, one could modify OPs `f0` function by including a `SymbolName`, in such a way that one passes a string to `Information`:

```
f0[sym_Symbol] := Information[SymbolName@Unevaluated@sym]
```